# which job map reduce can do but apache crunch can't?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-crunch

I'm studying about apache crunch. As far as i know, crunch is an abstraction framework based on map-reduce framework. I intend to use crunch instead of map-reduce framework.

My question is which job that map-reduce can do but crunch can't ?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is anything like which mapreduce can do and apache crunch can't. Apache crunch is a framework which works on top on Mapreduce just like Hive,Pig. In fact it makes the map reduce programming simple by writing DoFn's and the crunch takes care of implementing the business logic in map or reduce phase using its execution planner and engine. Concepts like joins can easily be implemented in crunch when compared to pure form of map reduce code.